# How to pass an array of double Image to mexFunction in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have already passed an image to my mexFunction but now I need to pass an array of images and I am struggling to get the thing right.  This is my code to get the simple Image.  This works perfectly but when I go into 3D I don't understand how the information is arranged in the mxArray.

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, mxArray *prhs[]) 
{
    mxArray *matrixIn = prhs[0];
    inputImage=(double *)mxGetPr(matrixIn);
    int x = int(dims[0]);
    int y = int(dims[1]);
    volume3D image(inputImage, x, y, 1);
}

volume3D::volume3D(double* image, int x, int y, int z) 
{
    allocateVolume( x, y, z); 
    for(int i=0; i<xSize; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<ySize; j++) {
            volume[i][j][0] = double(image[(i)*x+j]);
        }
}
```

I did something like this to pass it the other way around

mwSize mrows,ncols;
    mrows = mxGetM(prhs[0]);
    ncols = mxGetN(prhs[0]);

```
plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(mrows, ncols, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
double *matlabTumorMap = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
const int * dims = mxGetDimensions( plhs[0]);
int x = int(dims[0]);
int y = int(dims[1]);
int z = int(dims[2]);



mwIndex subs[3];
mexPrintf("x %i\n",x);
mexPrintf("y %i\n",y);
mexPrintf("z %i\n",z);
mxArray *matrixTumor = plhs[0];

for(subs[0]=0; subs[0]<x; subs[0]++)
    for(subs[1]=0; subs[1]<y; subs[1]++)
        for(subs[2]=0; subs[2]<z; subs[2]++)
        {
            mwIndex x = mxCalcSingleSubscript( matrixTumor,3,subs);
            matlabTumorMap[x] = tumorMap.getVoxel(subs[0],subs[1],subs[2]);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/apiref/bqoqnz0.html, there is a [`mxCalcSingleSubscript`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/apiref/mxcalcsinglesubscript.html) which helps you calculating these data.

Something like

```
    mxArray *matrixIn = prhs[0];
    volume3D image(matrixIn);
}

volume3D::volume3D(MxArray* matrixIn) 
{
    double * inputImage=(double *)mxGetPr(matrixIn);
    assert(mxGetNumberOfDimensions(matrixIn) >= 3)
    mwSize * dims = mxGetDimensions(matrixIn);
    int x = int(dims[0]);
    int y = int(dims[1]);
    int z = int(dims[2]);

    double * image = mxGetPr(matrixIn);

    mwIndex subs[3];

    allocateVolume( x, y, z); 
    for(subs[0]=0; subs[0]<x; subs[0]++)
        for(subs[1]=0; subs[1]<y; subs[1]++)
            for(subs[2]=0; subs[2]<z; subs[2]++) {
                mwIndex x = mxCalcSingleSubscript(matrixIn, 3, subs);
                /* <unsure> */volume[subs[0]][subs[1]][subs[2]]  /* </unsure> */ = image[x];
            }
```

BTW: Pay attention if mixing C and C++ - it can lead to even more headache due to name mangling etc.

Comment: It doesn't quite work, whenever I do that I get weird dimensions for my images, I get x 256 y 31744 z 593166384, when it's actually 256x256x100.

Comment: @Apoc sorry - `i` `j` `k` doesn't exist; there you would have to take the `subs` stuff as well. Where exactly do you get these values?

Comment: it's all good, but I stumbled accross another problem, I tried to do the opposite, make an array of double images from my volume but I get weird stuff, like if I had 4 images per image and they were downscaled on the y axis to fit the one image.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the thing right.

The only problem is your indexing, I think. you should write:

```
 volume[i][j][0] = double(image[i+j*x]);
```

and also you forgot to write:

```
mwSize* dims = mxGetDimensions(matrixIn);
```